# is it possible to call a method from another subclass in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to build a simulation for robotic behavior. I have a Robot parent abstract class, and a functioning NormalRobot subclass. I want to build a FaultyRobot subclass, possibly with something like partial "parallel" inheritance?

The parent class Robot has an abstact `move()` method, since I want all my Robot subclasses to be able to be called on with the same name `move()`

NormalRobot has a functioning method `move()` that simulates one "turn", of moving the specified distance in the specified direction. (multiple "turns" are simulated by calling `move()` multiple times)

FaultyRobot should also have a `move()` method, which is almost identical to the NormalRobot's move() except that at the start of the "turn" it randomly has a possibility of not moving and changing direction. Obviously I can do this by writing the randomness code (which i have in a helper method `turn_is_faulty()`) and copy-pasting the content of NormalRobot's `move()`. But obviously this is bad etiquete to have repeating code. Python inheritance  makes it very easy to inhereit the `move()` method from the parent class Robot, but I need the `move()` from the parallel subclass NormalRobot.

I'm imagining that the code would look something like

```
def Class FaultyRobot:
    def move(self):
        if self.turn_is_faulty():
            self.set_robot_direction(360 * random.random())
        else:
            #call the NormalRobot move()
```

Does Python allow some sort of partial "parallel" inheritance?

Comment: If the faulty class inherited from the normal class instead of the ABC, it could just call the `super` method. That's a bit of an awkward hierarchy though. You could also have an external/static method of the ABC that handles proper movement (instead of that being defined in the normal class), then have the normal class use that separate function directly, and have the faulty class use it conditionally.

Comment: What subclasses of `Robot` do you imagine would *not* use `NormalRobot.move` or a variation of it? Sounds more like `FaultyRobot` should inherit from `NormalRobot`. Another option would be for `Robot.move` to provide a default implementation, so that `FaultyRobot` has access to it via `super`.

Comment: Another perspective is that a normal robot is the same as a faulty robot, except its probability of having a faulty move is 0.

Comment: @chepner seeing NormalRobot as having a 0 probability of a faulty move is a brilliant perspective! thank you. However NormalRobot and FaultyRobot have other methods for other parts of their functioning that makes it unfeasible to have them fully inheriting from each other

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want the ABC move() to be abstract in part so that I can write other subclasses that have different algorithms for moving around, and so that I can then compare the efficiency of the different subclasses to each other. Here specifically the move() of FaultyRobot is almost the same as the move() of NormalRobot, but other subclasses might have entirely different content in their move() methods

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Faulty Robot" is just a "Normal Robot" with few faults.

```
import numpy as np

class NormalRobot():
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def move(self, d):
    self.x += d

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"Position: {self.x}"
  
class FaultyRobot(NormalRobot):
  def __init__(self, x, is_faulty=True):
    self.x = x
    self.is_faulty = is_faulty

  def turn_is_faulty(self):
    return self.is_faulty

  def move(self, d):
    if self.turn_is_faulty():
      self.x += np.random.random()
    else:
      super().move(d)
```

test:

```
n = NormalRobot(0)
f = FaultyRobot(0)
nf = FaultyRobot(0, False)

n.move(10)
nf.move(10)
f.move(10)

print (n, nf, f)
```

Output:

```
Position: 10 Position: 10 Position: 0.07103605819788694
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put shared functionality into a mixin class.

```
import random                                 
                                     
class AbstractRobot:
    """My 1 dimensional robot"""
    def __init__(self, start_at):
        self.pos = start_at
    
class RobotMoveMixin:

    def move(self, delta):
        self.pos += delta
        print('moved to', self.pos)

class GoodRobot(RobotMoveMixin, AbstractRobot):
    pass
    
class BadRobot(RobotMoveMixin, AbstractRobot):

    def move(self, delta):
        print("bad robot")
        if random.choice((True, False)):
            super().move(delta)

robot = BadRobot(0)
for _ in range(10):
    robot.move(3)
```

Now GoodRobot and its inheritors get the good movement while BadRobot and its interitors get the messed up one.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help. I ended up finding another solution that I think may be interesting, so I am posting it. My solution doesn't use inheritance in any formal sense, so I suspect some of you may have though of something like it but not posted it, since it seems far off from the phrasing of my question. This is my own problem, since I saw this an a problem with inheritance, and so I assumed the solution would be found with better inheritance structure. Thankfully there is a simple workaround.

```
def Class FaultyRobot:
    def move(self):
        if self.turn_is_faulty():
            self.set_robot_direction(360 * random.random())
        else:
            StandardRobot.move(self)
```

Python does indeed allow to call the `move()` of one subclass while defining the `move()` of a new subclass!